# COGNOS: Aggregation on time and other categories in dimensional Cube

Tags: reporting, cognos, dimensional-modeling

I would like to aggregate a measure based on time and two other categories. For that i have created 2 variables.

I would like to have the measure for the last month of the year based on 2 Variables [Gesamt Anzahl] and [Depots]

The first variable **[M_Akuell]** output shows the last month for example in 2018 it is 2018_M12

**item(tail(filter(members([ME_OBG_PRODUKT_M].[D_Zeit].[Periode].[Jahr_Monat]); tuple([Kennzahl]; currentMember([ME_OBG_PRODUKT_M].[D_Zeit].[Periode])) is not null); 1); 0)**

The second variable should be calculation of the  measure based on the time output from **[M_Aktuell]** and the 2 variables [Gesamt Anzahl] and [Depots]

**tuple([Kennzahl];[Gesamt Anzahl];[M_Aktuell];[Depots])**

But when i am using a singelton the measure is always calculated by all 12 months? Does anyone know where i have the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your expression is returning 2018_M12, I think its returning the year 2018 as you are using members which expands the entire hierarchy.  Usually the first member of that set is Year(All) or in your case the first year.  To prove this out simply project the pieces of your tuple expression in a crosstab to see what comes back.

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/14.3/"           useStyleVersion="11.4" expressionLocale="en">

                <drillBehavior/>
                <layouts>
                    <layout>
                        <reportPages>
                            <page name="Page1">
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                                <pageBody>
                                    <style>
                                        <defaultStyles>
                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                                        </defaultStyles>
                                    </style>
                                    <contents><crosstab horizontalPagination="true" name="Crosstab1" refQuery="Query1">
            <crosstabCorner>
                <contents><textItem><dataSource><dataItemLabel refDataItem="Revenue"/></dataSource></textItem></contents>
                <style>
                    <defaultStyles>
                        <defaultStyle refStyle="xm"/>
                    </defaultStyles>
                </style>
            </crosstabCorner>


            <noDataHandler>
                <contents>
                    <block>
                        <contents>
                            <textItem>
                                <dataSource>
                                    <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                </dataSource>
                                <style>
                                    <CSS value="padding:10px 18px;"/>
                                </style>
                            </textItem>
                        </contents>
                    </block>
                </contents>
            </noDataHandler>
            <style>
                <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                <defaultStyles>
                    <defaultStyle refStyle="xt"/>
                </defaultStyles>
            </style>
        <defaultMeasure refDataItem="Revenue"/><crosstabFactCell><contents><textItem><dataSource><cellValue/></dataSource></textItem></contents><style><defaultStyles><defaultStyle refStyle="mv"/></defaultStyles></style></crosstabFactCell><crosstabRows><crosstabNode><crosstabNodeMembers><crosstabNodeMember refDataItem="Order method type" edgeLocation="e1"><style><defaultStyles><defaultStyle refStyle="ml"/></defaultStyles></style><contents><textItem><dataSource><memberCaption/></dataSource></textItem></contents></crosstabNodeMember></crosstabNodeMembers></crosstabNode></crosstabRows><crosstabColumns><crosstabNode><crosstabNodeMembers><crosstabNodeMember refDataItem="Filter" edgeLocation="e2"><style><defaultStyles><defaultStyle refStyle="ml"/></defaultStyles></style><contents><textItem><dataSource><dataItemValue refDataItem="Filter"/></dataSource></textItem></contents></crosstabNodeMember></crosstabNodeMembers></crosstabNode></crosstabColumns></crosstab><singleton name="Singleton1" refQuery="Query1">
            <contents><textItem><dataSource><dataItemValue refDataItem="Data Item1"/></dataSource></textItem></contents>
        </singleton></contents>
                                </pageBody>
                            </page>
                        </reportPages>
                    </layout>
                </layouts>
            <XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2013-01-08T15:31:44.420Z"/></XMLAttributes><modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples_LG_DQ&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO Sales (analysis)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath><queries><query name="Query1"><source><model/></source><selection><dataItemMeasure name="Revenue"><dmMember><MUN>[Sales (analysis)].[Sales].[Revenue]</MUN><itemCaption>Revenue</itemCaption></dmMember><dmDimension><DUN>[Sales (analysis)].[Sales]</DUN><itemCaption>Sales</itemCaption></dmDimension><XMLAttributes><XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/></XMLAttributes></dataItemMeasure><dataItemLevelSet name="Order method type"><dmLevel><LUN>[Sales (analysis)].[Order method].[Order method].[Order method type]</LUN><itemCaption>Order method type</itemCaption></dmLevel><dmDimension><DUN>[Sales (analysis)].[Order method]</DUN><itemCaption>Order method</itemCaption></dmDimension><dmHierarchy><HUN>[Sales (analysis)].[Order method].[Order method]</HUN><itemCaption>Order method</itemCaption></dmHierarchy></dataItemLevelSet><dataItemSetExpression name="Filter"><expression>item(tail(filter(members([Sales (analysis)].[Time].[Time].[Month]),tuple([Sales (analysis)].[Sales].[Quantity], currentMember([Sales (analysis)].[Time].[Time])) is not null); 1), 0)</expression><dmDimension><DUN>[Sales (analysis)].[Time]</DUN><itemCaption>Time</itemCaption></dmDimension><dmHierarchy><HUN>[Sales (analysis)].[Time].[Time]</HUN><itemCaption>Time</itemCaption></dmHierarchy></dataItemSetExpression><dataItem name="Data Item1"><expression>tuple([Filter],[Revenue],[Sales (analysis)].[Order method].[Order method].[Order method type]-&gt;[Order method].[3])</expression></dataItem></selection></query></queries></report>
```

Comment: Thats the problem that i have - when i use it in a crosstab it displays the value of the month 2018_m12, but when i want to display the value in a singelton it shows the aggregation of the whole year

Comment: I just tested this against the samples and it appears to work.  Can you see if the spec I posted in the answer works for you and or what needs to change?

Comment: Thanks mate, i will try it :)